# Using Azure packages with .NET Core / MVC

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-mobile-services

I'm exploring Core MVC 1.0.

Is it possible to use Azure nuget packages I've been using in the past in previous Web API projects? For example, I've been using `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications` which gives me extension methods on `HttpConfiguration` that I can use in my controllers like:

```
var pushClient = Configuration.GetPushClient();
```

But I understand `HttpConfiguration` no longer exists.

Is there any way to use Azure packages like this with MVC controllers, or should I just be waiting until they release versions that target .net core? If so, are they even working on this? I can find anything anywhere.

Comment: You'll have to validate this on a library by library case. i.e. WindowsAzure.Storage library also has a preview support for CoreCLR https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/tree/master. For Azure Mobile Apps... well https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications/PushClient.cs#L31-L39 doesn't have any constructor that doesn't require `HttpConfiguration`, so it's quite sure to say, it won't work

Comment: But there is nothing which prevents you from grabbing the code, do the necessary changes (seems the configuration is only used to get an Instance of `IMobileAppSettingsProvider` https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications/PushClient.cs#L50, which you could inject via DI instead of the `HttpConfiguration` and use the DI/Configuration pattern to register it with the .NET Core Pipeline/DI system and hell create a pull request if that's all the changes required so others can profit from it too

Comment: Thanks. I tried to skip the Azure Mobile library bit and use Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs directly - all I was looking for was the NotificationHubClient - but it's not happy. "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0". Perhaps this is because this package required .NET 4.5 full profile? Is there anyway for it to work in a .net core project?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can work with ASP.NET Core packages targetting the Full Framework too. We have several apps that are targetting `netcoreapp` and others targetting `net461` due to Azure packages, but both use ASP.NET Core packages. Of course, this is valid if your environment has the Full Framework (Azure App Service does).

You can see how both the `netcoreapp` and `net46` versions go related to NetStandard [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms).

To achieve this, remove the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` from the `dependencies` and change `netcoreapp1.0` to `net461` on your `frameworks` declaration.

When the NetCore-compatible packages go live, just reverse the change and your app will keep working.

Comment: That won't help the OP much, if the dependency he wants to use directly uses `HttpConfiguration` like the notification libraries does in it's constructor which is true for most libraries which depend on `System.Web`  , since the new ASP.NET Core doesn't use anything from `System.Web` anymore

Comment: The [Azure Notification Hub nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) works fine with ASP.NET Core when running on the Full Framework (net461). It won't work when using `netcoreapp` but `net461` is still ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the Mobile Apps Server SDK support for ASP.NET Core, the work is on our backlog, but we don't have a timeline to share. This is partly because some of the dependencies (such as Asp.NET OData and OData) don't yet support ASP.NET Core.

In the meantime, you could try @matias-quaranta's answer for how to use both together.